# Using a callback function in setState

Tags: reactjs

I will like to use a callback function with setState and
get the updated value right away. I will need this value to be
passed to a function. The code below does not work. Nothing is displayed with the console.log. The console.log does not get hit.

How can I use callback in setState?

```
    searchForInvoicesByDates(startDate, endDate){

          this.setState({
            processInvoiceIds: filteredResult
          }, () => {
            console.log("This is Awesome");
            console.log(this.state.processInvoiceIds);    
            this.searchByInvoiceIds_ReturnsProducts(this.state.processInvoiceIds)        
        })

    }
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: *"does not work"* is a virtually meaningless problem statement

Comment: I am not able to hit the console.log. It does not return anything

Comment: Sounds like function isn't being called or errors exist. Provide  a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce your issue using code that is equivalent as far as i can tell (given the information you have provided). The log statements are reached and executed with the new value.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    processInvoiceIds: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      processInvoiceIds: [1, 2, 3],
    }, () => {
      console.log("This is awesome");
      console.log(this.state.processInvoiceIds);
    })
  }
  render () {
   return null
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('main'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```